# Monodevelopへコピペができない

Tags: unity3d

Windows7　Unity5.3

WEBページに記載されているコードをコピペしようとしてもMonodevelopへコピペができません。
確認のため、メモ帳へペーストするとペーストされます。

Monodevelop記載のコードから　別の　Monodevelop　のソースファイルへはコピペできます。
メモ帳からコピーしたものも、Monodevelopへはペーストできません。

Unityインストール時から得に設定を変えた覚えはありません。

Answer (score 1):

Monodevelop　の再起動で解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

同じく5.3.1p3のMonoでコピペできなくなる症状があります。
再起動したら直るようです。